# Sinatra design pattern

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to implement a Sintra like design pattern, but I can't wrap my head around the current implementation.

Take this code for example.

```
get "/path1" do
  # Do stuff
end

get "/path2" do
  # Do stuff
end
```

How come the first call to `get` doesn't block the main thread?

I'm trying to implement something similar.

```
work("some data 1")
work("some data 2")
work("some data 3")
```

Here, I want it to add `"some data n"` to some kind of queue, when there isn't any more `work` calls then I want it to start processing the data. I do not want to call `App.start` in the end of the file`.

Comment: What do you mean, "block the main thread"? `get` associates a path with a block.

Comment: How does it know when to start the server? If it starts it on the first call to `get` the main thread will be blocked and the second `get` wont be called.

Comment: It doesn't start it on the first call to get--it starts it after the script file is loaded. I understand your question now; hang on.

Comment: (There are a number of options, btw; some are easier than others. One would be to just to thread out the work as you go. You could put the work calls inside a block. Unless you `require` something you're already running a command, like `queue work.rb` as opposed to `ruby work.rb`, otherwise what's `work`? You might want to be a bit more specific with your requirements :)